# Publishing react native app with expo publish takes long time

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, expo-publish

Hello I'm trying to publish my app to Expo with publish. It's stuck on 'Uploading JavaScript bundles' for hours. What could be the problem? I have installed node modules, should I delete them? Thank you

Comment: I am having the same problem. I publish to expo, it creates the project in Expo but in VS Code it says "Uploading JavaScript bundles" and never ends.

When I go to the project in Expo and try to use it on my mobile device it gives error "The operation couldn't be completed. (EXNetwork error 403)"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: vasikpasik or @Thomas were you able to find the cause?

Comment: I couldn't see it in device at first, so I just killed it, and ran `expo start` and then in web metro bundler did publish again - this time it also ended with just "uploading JS bundles" but now it appeared in the app ! (seem that it only needed a re-run :-) )